# Paraview rotate fields

Tags: rotation, transformation, paraview

I am using Paraview 5.0.1. If any solution requires updating, I can try.

I want to programmatically obtain field plots (and corresponding PlotOverLine) of displacements and stresses in rotated coordinate systems.

What are appropriate/convenient/possible ways of doing this?

So far, I have created one Calculator filter for each component of displacements and stresses.
For instance, I used Calculators in 2D with results

```
(displacement.iHat)*cos(0.7853981625)+(displacement.jHat)*sin(0.7853981625)
(stress_3-stress_0)*sin(45.0*3.14159265/180)*cos(45.0*3.14159265/180)+stress_1*((cos(45.0*3.14159265/180))^2-(sin(45.0*3.14159265/180))^2)
```

It works fine, but it is quite cumbersome, in several aspects:

1. Creating them (one filter per component).
2. Plotting several of them in a single XY plot
3. Exporting them (one export per component).

**Is there a simple way to do this?**

PS: The `Transform` filter does not accomplish this. It rotates the view, not the fields.

Comment: Should be doable in a single programmable filter. Did you try it ? Also could you share the initial dataset and final dataset ?

Comment: @MathieuWestphal - I am not familiar with programmable filters. I understand they give flexibility, but I suspected there might be something already in place for this, either in a single filter or a combination of a few.
What do you mean by the initial and final datasets? The fields before and after rotation? For the first, I could share a vtu file (what i am using as an input). For the second, I would have to export as csv the results. I do not see how would that help in guiding the answer (would you mind commenting?) Anyway, I will get back when the files are posted.

Comment: @MathieuWestphal - Where do you suggest I can post the files?

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

1. Ugly, inneficient solution

   - Use Transform and check "Transform All Input vectors"
   - Add a calculator and add a dummy array
   - Use transform the other way around, without checking "Transform All Input vectors"
2. Correct solution : 
   Compute the transformation yourself in a programmable filter

   ```
   input = self.GetUnstructuredGridInput();
   output =  self.GetUnstructuredGridOutput();
   output.ShallowCopy(input)

   data = input.GetPointData().GetArray("YourArray")

   vec = vtk.vtkDoubleArray();
   vec.SetNumberOfComponents(3);
   vec.SetName("TransformedVectors");

   numPoints = input.GetNumberOfPoints()
   for i in xrange(0, numPoints):
       tuple = data.GetTuple(i)
       transform(tuple) # implement the transform in python
       vec.InsertNextTuple(tuple)

   output.GetPointData().AddArray(vec)
   ```

Comment: Thanks.
Solution 1: I do not see any "Transform All Input vectors" check box. Could you point me to where it is?
Solution 2: I will try and get back.

Comment: "Transform All Input vectors" is a new option, you can download the last nightly version of paraview to get it. https://www.paraview.org/download/

Comment: Just use the last nightly, you should be fine

Comment: No, only in the not yet released 5.5 (march 2018)

Comment: Great. I started tweaking with option 2, and it seems it will do the trick (still to complete, verify speed, etc.). Thanks!

Comment: I still have to complete testing it... Of course I will accept the answer if it works.

Comment: I didn't have the chance to test it (things get in the way...). I think it might be misleading if I accept it without at least trying something. Will do!